# AngularJS updating model from directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, directive, jquery-steps

I have an Angular directive, which displays account details for a user to be able to amend and update. I'm using the `link` function in the directive to fire some javascript after the directive is rendered.

My problem is when the value's in the `input` is amended by the user, the base model `directiveShippingAccount` doesn't reflect the updates.

**How do I bind any updates back to the `directiveShippingAccount` model, so that I can save the updated values?**

Below is the directive in the main HTML page

```
<account-wizard directive-shipping-account="shippingAccount"
                        directive-bind-account-directive="bindAccountDirective()"
                        directive-save-shipping-account="saveShippingAccount(a)">
</account-wizard>
```

Below is a snippet from my HTML template for the `account-wizard` directive

```
<div class="row">
    <h2>Please enter your details below</h2>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 ">
    <input type="text" class="text-center form-control required" ng-model="directiveShippingAccount.CollectionAddress.company" placeholder="Company name" value="{{directiveShippingAccount.company}}" />
        <input type="text" class="text-center form-control required" ng-model="directiveShippingAccount.ShippingAccountNumber" placeholder="Royal Mail Account Number" value="{{directiveShippingAccount.ShippingAccountNumber}}" />
        <input type="text" class="text-center form-control required" ng-model="directiveShippingAccount.AllowedNDCodes" placeholder="Service Codes" value="{{directiveShippingAccount.AllowedNDCodes}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the directive itself

```
labulo.directive('accountWizard', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        templateUrl: '../Scripts/angular/directives/templates/AccountWizard.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            directiveShippingAccount: "=",
            directiveBindAccountDirective: "&",
            directiveSaveShippingAccount: "&"
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.directiveBindAccountDirective();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can access controller scope value using $parent. Like this, in directive, you can do something like $scope.$parent.someModel to update value in controller

Comment: There must be an Angular way to do 2-way data binding though?

Comment: have you tried to use a watcher?

Comment: Not sure how to implement a watcher properly. I think it's something to do with `directiveBindAccountDirective()` which breaks the 2-way binding. This function basically fires the jQuery steps wizard on the form, but if I comment it out the 2-way bind seems to work